# Different positioning of views within the design panel vs Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-emulator

A major difference appears between the positioning of the views within the design panel and when running the same layout on the emulator:

- [Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htVlm.png)
- [Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySR3P.png)

Question: Why does this difference appear?

EDIT:

Here is the XML for the layout with certain modifications.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/beispiel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onSelectDas"
    android:text="Neue checkliste"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="37dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="658dp" />

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="618dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="618dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="562dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Checkliste"
                android:layout_width="401dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**What are those modifications:** Deleted certain views, left only one button, which will be at the Bottom: "Neue Checkliste" and also left only one Tab at the Top: "Checkliste"

Comment: Post the actual code.  You can't tell anything from a picture of the design tool.  I suggest not even using it, learn how to write the layouts as xml (because that's what they are anyway, and that's how the emulator or device will interpret them).

Comment: Ok, Thank you, i just expected for the tool to be working properly.

Comment: Short answer: layout_editor_absoluteX and layout_editor_absoluteY are just visual for the editor, they have no actual effect on the app's rendering.  Is this in a ConstraintLayout?  You're missing the top level of the XML file

Comment: In addition to layout_editor_absoluteX not being listened to via devices, generally if you're specifying sizes and locations like that you're not doing Android UI right.  To work well on mutiple devices our UI should maximize positioning via constraints and relative sizes, and minimize hard coded numbers.  390dp might look ok on a phone, its not going to look right on a tablet.  Or on a phone in landscape mode.  Or on a phone that's .5 inches bigger than the one you tested on.  Hardcoding a size is *almost* always wrong.